# How can I connect Bluetooth speakers to Ubuntu Studio 23.10 amd64

Tags: bluetooth

I downloaded a recent Ubuntu Studio 23.10, and wanted to try it before I install it to disk. Reason is that I want to try if audio stuff works better than on my Debian Trixie installation. Basically, I want to use BT speakers and headset to listen to stuff I do in Ardour.

I ran into two issues:

1. How can I identify to which Bluetooth device to connect to? When scanning devices, the dialog presents a list of available BT devices, but only their MAC addresses.
2. When I try to connect to each device in turn, most of them fail and for some a PIN is shown which I need to use to pair to those devices. Using this procedure, I needed to restart Ubuntu Studio several times (because after some devices it wont even detect devices anymore) in order to find the Sony Hear-Go BT speaker, just to find out that a PIN is presented that I have to use to pair to the speaker. I can not enter a PIN on the BT speaker and I never had to with Debian based systems or Windows.

Of course I can boot another system and write down the MAC addresses, but I never had to do this with other systems. And the machine is connected to Internet via WIFI, just in case a lookup is needed to resolve MAC addresses to device names. But this does not seem to be the case.